# Is there any way to save drumsticks or mana bottles?

Tags: rogue-legacy

Sometimes when I break something, it will drop either a drumstick (restores health) or a mana bottle (restores mana). Is there any way to save those for later, or to know where they will drop from, so I don't waste them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After being dropped, these items will disappear when leaving the room.

But, every Boss Room and Teleportation Room has 2 statues in it. The left always drops a drumstick, and the right a mana bottle. That is, unless if your character is Gay in which case the right drops the drumstick and the left drops the mana. If you dont smash them when you first encounter them, you can return later to get these items.

The moving drumsticks that appear for characters with alektorphobia still remain if left alive when you leave a room.

Comment: Very important update: If you have the Alektorphobia trait, and leave a chicken running around in a room, it will stay there and not despawn, thus making it possible to save drumsticks for later.

Answer (score 0):

Drops are (for the most part) random, so you can't tell where or when they'll drop. Also, from what I can recall, you can't save those restoration items for latter, other than not picking them up.

Comment: Though, I need to check if items de-spawn if one moves offscreen.

Comment: They do. And there are a few places where there always seems to be both a drumstick and a mana bottle. I'm pretty sure they always show up in boss rooms and teleporter rooms.

Comment: Hmm, I'll test that theory out and then edit my original answer.

Answer (score -1):

What I do is leave objects that drop items intact while I explore and/or wait to break them open until I have cleared all enemies in a room/area. 
Eat some now, save some for later, if you know what I mean.
This also helps me quickly get "the lay of the land" and gather major loot $!!$

TIP : Use the Sprint and Vault runes and you can move thru rooms very quickly.